Residing seasonal cabin
I need some opinions about some renovations I am making to my cabin. For background, this is a cottage in NW Wisconsin that we use in the warmer months.  It is lightly insulated so heat loss is not necessarily a concern.  If it was I'd have a whole lot more work.
I am going to be residing the cabin with DiamondKote ridgid stack siding.  The way they cabin was built is that they put 8in grooved plywood siding directly on the studs.  There may be a plastic sheet barrier behind the plywood but I am not sure about that.  We had some rot of the plywood at the very bottom where snow had contacted the plywood.  I have cut that bottom 2ft or so off and replaced with treated plywood.  My plan is to just lay the diamond kote directly over the plywood as that would now act as the sheathing without doing a house wrap.
Is this an OK thing to do or am I missing something big.

If you cut off and replaced the bottom two feet of plywood, you either found plastic between it and the studs, or you didn't. If you didn't, it's not there. No reason for a vapor barrier in an unheated / uncooled cabin anyway.

You can go right over plywood siding with tons of options.    It is more about how much you want to spend and what you want it to look like.    You can get leftover vinyl for 1/5th of the price of hardie sheets which would give you the same kind of look.

Someone else did the bottom two feet when I was having some joist work done.  So that is why I don't know.  Thanks for the answers.
